# Import python functions into a .NET language?

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I am a C# .NET programmer and am learning Python.  I have downloaded IronPython, and know that it can call into .NET libraries.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to do the reverse, that is to call into some existing "classic" Python libraries in my C# code, maybe using .NET Interop.

I'd like to be able to access functions in libraries such as pygame.

Answer (score 5):

Ironpython 2.0 is CPython 2.5 compatible, so pure Python that uses <=2.5 APIs should work fine under Ironpython. I believe Ironpython code can then be compiled into a DLL.

For C-extensions like Pygame, you might want to take a look at [Ironclad](http://code.google.com/p/ironclad/). It's a project to allow for C-extensions to be used within Ironpython. This may also give you the native code bridge you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Python for .Net](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/), which allows you to 'use CLR services and continue to use existing Python code and C-based extensions while maintaining native execution speeds for Python code.'

Further, 'A key goal for this project has been that Python for .NET should "**work just the way you'd expect in Python**", except for cases that are .NET specific (in which case the goal is to work "just the way you'd expect in C#"). In addition, with the IronPython project gaining traction, it is my goal that code written for IronPython run without modification under Python for .NET.'

Hope this helps